# why cant pass values directly to threads in c

Tags: c, pthreads

While creating a thread in C using

```
pthread_create(thread,attr,start_routine,arg)
```

Why should we cast the arguments to thread function,using (void *) and cast it back to original type in the thread functions..
Why can't just pass the values directly ... ?

```
 void * fun(void *a){
     int x = (int)a;
     printf("Helloword %d \n",x);
     pthread_exit(NULL);
 }

 int main()
 {
     int a=9;
     pthread_t t;
     pthread_create(&t,NULL,fun,(void *)a);
     pthread_exit(NULL);
     return 1;
 }
```

Comment: Because the API has to be general.

Comment: Because `pthread_create` takes a `void *`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the prototype of the `pthread_create` function calls for `void*`.  This allows a maximum of flexibility for developers as to what can be passed to the function.  That way there is only a need for one prototype instead of lots of different ones with different types of parameters.

Comment: just to be sure,the warning `cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]`  is normal ,right ...?

Comment: @halfdreamer, It is normal if you're doing something bad. Pass a pointer in, don't just cast things. For example, with assurance that `a` lives long enough, `&a`. Then in `fun`, `int *x = a;`

Comment: The warning is because when you cast, the pointer is a different size than the int.

Comment: @chris, how the void pointer changes to int without type casting .. ?

Comment: @halfdreamer, C allows implicit `void *` to `T *` conversions.